# Vuetify 3 presets

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, material-design, vuetifyjs3

I was using a preset vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-preset-reply based on Material Studies Reply Vuetify 2. Do you know how to use it in vuetify 3?

I've checked the new documentation but there isn't any information about presets like in previous doc.

Comment: I think those are called [blueprints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/blueprints/) now